# SE should check the leaderboard before lying to me!

Tags: bug

I got this like many other users of the site.

> [image]

Except, I didnt make it to the leaderboard. I have 151 rep, while the leaderboard starts at 200+ rep. If SE is going to send me an email for simply participating, then atleast make it accurate :)

Comment: Same here, with 103 rep

Comment: We didn't lie to you, in an alternate universe you really did make the leaderboard (in all seriousness, I'm checking into this).

Comment: Thanks. It will be great to know which universe that is.